# Does stocking my refrigerator with canned drinks (Cola) consume more energy?

Tags: electricity, refrigerant

I have in my refrigerator relatively few products. However, I always have a 2 week supply of Cola cans. That is, I put the cans in much earlier than I consume them.

Does my large supply of Coke cans require more energy to cool or is the difference barely noticeable?

Should I stop putting cans of cola in advance in the fridge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you shouldn't stop that. It's just thermal mass.

The consumption of refrigerator is determined by two factors:

1. How easily heat leaks inside the refrigerator through the insulated walls
2. How often you open the refrigerator to let warm air in

Factor (1) is independent of the amount of cola cans inside. Presumably factor (2) is too, so if having refrigerator full of cola cans doesn't cause you to open it more often, it doesn't increase energy usage.

However, it increases thermal mass. This is actually a good thing because if you have a power outage, the more thermal mass there is inside the refrigerator, the longer it takes for the temperature to increase to a problematic level.

I have purposefully put containers full of 40 liters of water into one of my refrigerators, and containers full of 30 liters of water into the other. This thermal mass allows them to survive longer power cuts.

Comment: More stuff in the fridge also reduces the amount of air, so with an upright fridge less air falls out when you open the door. Drawer fridges and chest fridges have much less of a problem with that.

Comment: Oh that's true indeed. So if your refrigerator is full and you open the door often, it could actually consume less energy!

Comment: I tend to agree with this answer providing the temperature of the cans is always the same when they are placed in the fridge. If the cans first stay in a "cool room" where the temperature is, say 20C or less, then it takes less effort to cool the cans to 4C, when they are in the fridge. If however, the cans have been in a hot location, the car on a hot day for hours, & their temperature is 30C or higher, then it takes more effort to cool them. If it's hot today & you know it will be cooler in 7 days, may be place half the can in now & the rest when it's cooler.